# windowsアプリの署名

Tags: windows, electron

electronでwindowsアプリを作っているんですが、署名に関して分からないことがあります。

1. 署名に使う証明書はSSL用のものでもいいのか
2. macのpcから署名することは可能か
3. 経験者の方で参考になるサイトがあれば教えて下さい

詳しい方ご教授ください。よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
証明書はコード用のものが必要でした。macからでも可能でした。

Comment: 自己解決した場合は、自分の回答を承認することが、推奨されています。